# Field in the class Record with generic type

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typescript-typings

I need a list of defined schedules with their types and I want to use a "defined" object for this, but I can't pass a generic type to it, is that possible?

Here's the code I have, but it throws an error and I can't pass it the types it needs

```
@Injectable()
export class SchedulerService {
  private readonly scheduler: Agenda;
  private readonly defined: Record<string, Processor<T>> = {};
  // or   private readonly defined: Map<string, Processor<T>> = new Map();

  constructor(private readonly config: ConfigService) {
    this.scheduler = new Agenda({
      db: { address: this.config.get('MONGO_URI'), collection: 'AgendaJobs' },
    });

    this.scheduler.start();
  }

  getDefined() {
    return this.defined;
  }

  getDefinedNames() {
    return Object.keys(this.defined);
  }

  async defineSchedule<T>(name: string, callback: Processor<T>, context: any) {
    this.defined[name] = callback.bind(context);

    this.scheduler.define<T>(name, callback.bind(context));
  }

  async createSchedule<T>(time: string | Date, name: string, data: T) {
    const job = await this.scheduler.schedule<T>(time, name, {
      time,
      ...data,
    });

    return String(job.toJSON()._id);
  }

  async cancelJobs(filter: FilterQuery<Document>) {
    return await this.scheduler.cancel({ ...filter, nextRunAt: { $ne: null } });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In classes, you need to define the generic type next to the name of class and then you can use it inside.
Here how it should look like:

```
export class SchedulerService<T> {
  private readonly scheduler: Agenda;
  private readonly defined: Record<string, Processor<T>> = {};
  // or   private readonly defined: Map<string, Processor<T>> = new Map();

  constructor(private readonly config: ConfigService) {
    this.scheduler = new Agenda({
      db: { address: this.config.get('MONGO_URI'), collection: 'AgendaJobs' },
    });

    this.scheduler.start();
  }

  getDefined() {
    return this.defined;
  }

  getDefinedNames() {
    return Object.keys(this.defined);
  }

  async defineSchedule(name: string, callback: Processor<T>, context: any) {
    this.defined[name] = callback.bind(context);

    this.scheduler.define<T>(name, callback.bind(context));
  }

  async createSchedule(time: string | Date, name: string, data: T) {
    const job = await this.scheduler.schedule<T>(time, name, {
      time,
      ...data,
    });

    return String(job.toJSON()._id);
  }

  async cancelJobs(filter: FilterQuery<Document>) {
    return await this.scheduler.cancel({ ...filter, nextRunAt: { $ne: null } });
  }
}
```